# Обрезать строку от и до

Tags: php

Получаю только нужный мне текст из строки таким образом:

```
$new = stristr($str, '<h2>Test Apple</h2>');
$new = stristr($new, '<div class="block">text</div>', true);
```

В итоге я получаю все что от `<h2>Test Apple</h2>` и до `<div class="block">text</div>`

Но в строке может быть и так: `<h2>Test Gold</h2>`

И тогда мне хотелось бы иметь что-то вроде:

```
$new = stristr($str, '<h2>Test (*любые символы)</h2>');
$new = stristr($new, '(*любые символы отличные от <p(*любые символы)', true);
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: используйте либо библиотеки синтаксического разбора HTML ([tag:simple_html_dom]), либо [tag:регулярные-выражения].

Comment: @teran я уже использую simple_html_dom, но вот еще понадобилось сделать то что указано в вопросе. я думаю тут нужны регулярные выражения - но я в них не силен(